# what is the difference between must and must be?

Tags: modal-verbs

I do not know which answer is correct?
(I suppose the first one shows how likely it is that he is doing that activity right now)

A: He does not answer his phone!

B: He must be driving  or He must drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*He must be driving* is correct in this context. It implies that he is actually driving now and that is the reason he cannot answer.
*He must drive* has two possible other meanings.
Either it is a necessary activity "He lives right out in the country so *he must drive* to get anywhere" [but he is not necessarily driving right now]
Or "*He must drive* everywhere* - He has a compulsion to drive everywhere [but doesn't have to do so]
There is also drive as used in Golfing "To get off the green *he must drive* the ball up the fairway.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.